# Pre and post increment confusion

Tags: c

I tried running this program :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
        int a=5;
        printf("%d %d", ++a,a++);
        return 0;
}
```

with gcc in arch-chroot on a armv7 device. I expect to get output `7 5` but i'm getting `7 6`. Can anyone explain what's going on?[image: running the program]

Comment: You are assuming a left to right evaluation order of the arguments.

Comment: Also, if the arguments were evaluated from left to right, wouldn't the result be  `6 6`

Comment: yes. It would be... I think it's neither following right to left order or left to right order. What's the matter? right to left `7 5` . left to right `6 6`

Comment: Read assembler source if you're really curious. Many x86 compilers would produce 7 5. But it's another architecture. And it's UB anyway.

Comment: And please post text as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is invoking *Undefined Behavior* (UB)!

Use the warning flgas `-Wall -Wextra` during compilation, and the compiler will tell you the story:

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:4:30: warning: operation on 'a' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
    4 |         printf("%d %d", ++a,a++);
      |                             ~^~
7 5
```

In that <kbd>[online demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dgUvEweiAH5zEl9J)</kbd>, I got a different output, a characteristic of UB.

Read more in [printf and ++ operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319565/printf-and-operator).

Answer (score 1):

[6.5p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p2)

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either
>   a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value
>   computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is
>   undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the
>   subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an
>   unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.84)

`++a` and `a++` are unsequenced. Your program is ill-formed.