# Why does printf output this in my program?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d",printf("%d %d",2,2) & printf("%d %d",2,2));
}
```

The output comes like this: `2 2 2 2 3`

I cannot figure out why the output is like this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`printf` returns the numbers of characters printed, so here is the explanation:

```
printf("%d",printf("%d %d",2,2) & printf("%d %d",2,2));
\_________/ \_________________/ | \_________________/
     |              |           |          |
     |         prints "2 2"     |    prints "2 2"
     |         and returns 3    |    and returns 3
     |                          |
     |                    computes 3 & 3
     |                   (which equals 3)
     |
 prints "3"
```

Comment: +1 for noting why the return values from `printf` are what they are.

Comment: Note that the order of the evaluation of the two `printf("%d %d", 2, 2)` expressions isn't defined by the standard, but they print the same thing either way, so I don't know whether it's undefined behavior or not.

Comment: @Chris: Why would it be undefined behavior?

Comment: @GMan - If the order of evaluation of the arguments of `&` is undefined then the order the side effects happen is undefined. I think? (Or is it just the order of evaluation of function arguments that is undefined?)

Comment: @GMan: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376278/parameter-evaluation-order-before-a-function-calling-in-c/395991#395991

Comment: @Chris: The order arguments to a function are evaluated is unspecified. Operators, though, have *associativity*, and are evaluated either left-to-right, or right-to-left. The `&` (bitwise-and) operator evaluates left-to-right, so the left-hand `printf` gets evaluated first (called first).

Comment: @sarnold: I know, but the bitwise-and operator is not a function.

Comment: @GMan - 6.5, paragraph 3: "The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax. Except as speciﬁed later (for the function-call(), &&, ||, ?:, and comma operators), the order of evaluation of subexpressions and the order in which side effects takeplace are both unspeciﬁed."

Comment: And 6.5.13 (about logical `&&`) specifically mentions the difference between `&&` (which guarantees evaluation order) and `&` (which doesn't): "Unlike the bitwise binary `&` operator, the `&&` operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; there is a sequence point after the evaluation of the ﬁrst operand. If the ﬁrst operand compares equal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated"

Comment: @Chris: Ah, look at that. I thought it was functions only. I revoke my previous statement, though I still don't see where UB enters.

Comment: @GMan - It's unspecified, which is also bad but doesn't affect this example since both inner `printf` calls produce the same result regardless.

Comment: @Chris: Right, but if they didn't that shouldn't change anything. It just isn't specified which text appears first.

Comment: @GMan - At this point we're just vehemently agreeing with each other. When I started this I thought it was undefined (instead of unspecified) behavior, and thus that the compiler would be allowed to do anything with the code.