# C/C++ post-increment/-decrement and function call

Tags: c++, c, function, call, post-increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

I am using microsoft visual c++. Look at the following example:

```
int n = 5;
char *str = new char[32];
strcpy(str, "hello world");
memcpy(&str[n], &str[n+1], 6+n--);
printf(str);
// output is "hell world"
```

So unexpectadly my compiler produces code that **first** decrements n and then executes memcpy. The following source will do what i expected to happen:

```
int n = 5;
char *str = new char[32];
strcpy(str, "hello world");
memcpy(&str[n], &str[n+1], 6+n);
n--;
printf(str);
// output is "helloworld"
```

First I tried to explain it to myself. The last parameter gets pushed on the stack first, so it may be evaluated first. But I really believe that post increment/decrement guarantee to be evaluated after the next semicolon.

So I ran the following test:

```
void foo(int first, int second) {
    printf("first: %i / second: %i", first, second);
}
int n = 10;
foo(n, n--);
```

This will output "first: 10 / second: 10".

So my question is: Is there any defined behaviour to this situation? Can somebody point me to a document where this is described? Have I found a compiler bug ~~O.O~~?

The example is simplyfied to not make sence anymore, it just demonstrates my problem and works by itself.

Comment: Is there any defined behaviour => no

Comment: @ipc: This is puzzling me every time: why is the behavior "undefined" rather than just "unspecified"? Isn't just the order of evaluation of the arguments which is unspecified?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376278/parameter-evaluation-order-before-a-function-calling-in-c

Comment: @AndyProwl the order of evaluation is unspecified, accessing the same variable and modifying it in an unsequenced fashion is undefined. Oh wait, I think I misread your question...

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Right, I found that out. For a scalar that's indeed so (*"If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined"*). But if it wasn't a scalar, that would not be undefined behavior, right?

Comment: @AndyProwl I think it's still undefined behaviour, but I don't have a standard reference, let me find it.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: That's indeed what I should deduce from (unexplained) answers given by other people, but I can't find a reference in the standard.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Can you think of a side effect not involving scalars? (ok, writing to and reading from a file, but then only the order is unspecified). Note that I didn't use the word "undefined" in my comment.

Comment: @ipc: I've been told that this is UB even if the operand of `++` is a class object for which `++` has been overloaded. I do not understand why that's true though and I would like to find out.

Comment: @ipc: Yes, I've noticed you haven't used the word "undefined", but I thought you meant to imply it (and it is indeed correct in this case).

Comment: @AndyProwl: If the ++ operator is overloaded and it does nothing, why should there be UB? If it does something (i.e. modifying a scalar) it becomes UB because "a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced ..."

Comment: @ipc: let me complete the sentence: "...relative to either another side effect on the **same** scalar object or a value computation using the value of the **same** scalar object". So the ++ operator could do something (e.g. increment an iterator) and yet this should yield no UB. Or am I missing something?

Comment: `f(n, n++)` for example is indeed well defined if `operator++` only increments an iterator that is not read when evaluating or converting `n`.

Comment: @ipc: Well, that's what I thought. But when I wrote something similar, I was told I was wrong by reliable sources - who unfortunately did not care to explain any further.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two related issues at play. First, the order of execution of function arguments is **unspecified**. What is guaranteed is that all are executed before entering the body of the function. Second, it is **undefined** behaviour because you are changing and reading `n` without any sequence points between those expressions.

Comment: Thank you. I knew about the unspecified order of execution on arguments, but didn't know this affected the post operators. I thought they would always be executed after the next semicolon.