# post increment statement in printf

Tags: c

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i=8;
    printf("%d,%d,%d,%d\n",i--, --i, i++, i++);
    return 0;
}
```

the output in my machine is

> 9,8,8,8

I know printf executes args from right to left, but the output is seems unexpected, what's wrong here?

Comment: What's wrong here? Your expectations. This is undefined behavior. Please read the comp.lang.c FAQ (http://c-faq.com/expr/index.html)

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695681/c-c-post-increment-decrement-and-function-call

Comment: This is a duplicate of a lot of other questions.

Comment: http://codepad.org/BjzfKbBP,  http://codepad.org/4PhPRGcb

Comment: "I know printf executes args from right to left". It doesn't, you can't know or assume which order it evaluates them, it is unspecified behavior. It may even evaluate them in different order from call to call.