# Strange cout output (code blocks codeblocks-16.01mingw-setup.exe)

Tags: c++

When I run this program I get strange output 1132. Can somebody explan me why is 1132?

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int f1(int &a){return a++;}
int f2(int &a){return ++a;}

int main(){
    int x, y;
    int *px, *py;
    x = 1;
    y = 2;
    px = &x;
    py = &y;
    cout << f1(*px) << *px << f2(*py) << *py << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that the expressions are evaluated left to right.

Comment: 1233 for me. You're invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: It is totally depand on compiler. In your case expression is evaluated from right to left . :)

Comment: @Shloim: really? In this case, with `operator<<(std::ostream, T)`, I'd have expected this to be `((cout << f1(*px)) << *px)` etc., in which case a left-to-right evaluation would be guaranteed?

Comment: The `<<` is evaluated left to right, but the expressions between each pair of `<<` were evaluated right-to-left

Comment: Here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669493/c-why-does-llvm-evaluate-printf-left-to-right-when-gcc-evaluates-right-to-left

Comment: @Shloim: Of course, thanks! I forgot that while this guarantees the order of the calls to `<<`, it doesn't introduce any sequence points.

Comment: Well, anyone who writes code like this gets what they deserve. This does not seem like a "practical programming problem" to me.

Comment: #offtopic: you should really use `endl` instead oh `'\n'`

Answer (score 2):

The order of evaluation in your case was right-to-left.

Note that there is no guarantee for a left-to-right evaluation.

So order was:

1. `*py`
2. `f2(*py)`
3. `*px`
4. `f1(*px)`

Only then the `<<` operators ran (and were evaluated left-to-right as expected)

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
cout << f1(*px) << *px << f2(*py) << *py << "\n";
```

The compiler is free to evaluate each expression in any order (even though the order of execution of operator<< is left to right).

The expressions are:

```
f1(*px)
f2(*py)
*px
*py
```

The evaluation order may be any one of the npr(4,4) permutations.

npr(4,4) = 4! / (4-4)! = 24

Do you feel lucky?