# different output than expected while using pointers

Tags: c

I couldn't figure out the reason for the output I got:-

```
    int ar[5] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
    int *p = ar;
    printf("%d\t%d\n", *p, *(p++));
```

output: 3    1

but i expected : **1   3** as  p points to the 1st element and p++ points to the 2nd element.

Comment: Hint: `printf("%d\n", *p);` prints 1, as you expected.

Comment: I do not think this is UB. I believe it is *implementation specific*, which is different. (Not any better to rely on, though)

Answer (score 7):

Order of evaluation for function arguments is unspecified.

Comment: True but that's not the main problem...what we have is UB here.

Comment: @BlueMoon Paragraph 5/4 `Between the previous and next sequence point a scalar object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.` I only see one modification, but I might be wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

order of evaluation from right to left evaluate *(p++) first and increase the address then evaluate *p which now point to next element.Try *(p+1) instead of it.

Comment: i know that *(p+1) gives 3, but i wanna know what's wrong with my code

Comment: nothing wrong in your code! It just parameter evaluation result and note that parameter evalution is undefined. For looking more comment on this topic go <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviours-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-a>

Answer (score 0):

This gives a nice example how order of evaluation for function arguments
is not granted.

[Parameter evaluation order before a function calling in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376278/parameter-evaluation-order-before-a-function-calling-in-c)