# How it makes the output "fffffffe"?

Tags: c

How this program makes the following output?
Program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("%x", -1<<1);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Output

```
fffffffe
```

Comment: Which of the things are you confused about, the result of the calculation `-1<<1` or the result of the `x` formatter. Also, what did you expect? What result would not have made you raise your eyebrows?

Comment: Yeah - looks like a reasonable result to me: 0b11111111111111111111111111111110

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer. This will indicate to the community that  you found a solution and will give some reputation to you and the answerer.

Answer (score 3):

Left shift of a negative signed integer value is undefined in C.

> 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators
>
> 4. The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with
>    zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2 E2 , reduced modulo
>    one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If E1 has *a signed
>    type and nonnegative value*, and E1 × 2 E2 is representable in the result type, then that is
>    the resulting value; *otherwise, the behavior is undefined.*

In your case the type of `-1` is `signed int`.
The result you're seeing isn't meaningful and is an artifact of the architecture.

Comment: _undefined behaviour_ actually is a bit worse than just "undefined". It is something to definitively avoid.

Comment: correct, an "*artifact of the architecture*" which interprets `-1*2` resulting in `-2` by its bit-pattern as an `unsigned int` when printing (on this specific implementation on this specific architecture). The result might be different somewhere else.

Comment: @Olaf Do you have a good C only link on ub? I feel like there should be one that is highly upvoted but I can't find it.

Comment: @alk Yes. Can I include that in the answer? Off-topic: I would love to hear your opinion on this question if you have the time (it isn't urgent): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597855/c-order-of-evaluation-of-assignment-statement

Comment: Sure, go ahead ... :-)

Comment: "*link on ub*": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior

Comment: I see @alk already provided a link. However, Wikipedia has an article about it (for various languages) and the standard provides a definition in []3.4.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3) along with the other kinds of behaviour (miss-behaviour, mister-behaviour, etc.:-).