# printf() function evaluation of pre and post decrements in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 2;
    printf("\n %d %d %d \n",--i,i--,i);    //   0 2 2
    return 0;
}
```

The output prints `0 2 0` and not `0 2 2`.I couldn't understand, as I assumed that the `printf()` evaluates from right to left.

Comment: TL;DR undefined behaviour.

Comment: Not expected this from a 2K+ rep user!

Comment: Sorry forget to look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376278/parameter-evaluation-order-before-a-function-calling-in-c

Comment: Unforgettable... actually, no.

Comment: This question comes up on SO about once every couple of weeks.

Comment: @lurker; To be frank, That's not a exact dupe.

Comment: @lurker or twice, and it's the sequence point problem.

Comment: ..and nobody really cares anyway because all such code is garbage.

Comment: @5gon12eder: How so? It's not even about the same _language_!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, overlooked that it was about C++ although it doesn't matter for this particular issue but I agree that mixing the languages is teaching the wrong thing.  Here is a C one but i don't know how I can change my close vote. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior

Comment: @5gon12eder: That is obviously not a duplicate. Read [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duplicate)

Answer (score 4):

Your code exhibits [Unspecified behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior). As per `c99` standard document, chapter 6.5.2.2, paragraph 10:

> The order of evaluation of the function designator, the actual arguments, and subexpressions within the actual arguments is unspecified, but there is a sequence point *before* the actual call.

Again, this shows [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because, `i` is getting modified *more than once* between two sequence points. As per chapter 6.5 paragraph 2:

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.

Comment: That's the right answer.

Comment: No it's not. Unspecified behaviour and undefined behaviour are not the same thing. If this is UB it is because the variables are written to and read from multiple times without sequencing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Very true. Updated my answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit; Yeah not the same thing but former results in later. C11 removed the para which says that modifying a variable twice between two sequence points results in UB. It introduces **Sequence**.

Comment: This is better now. +1 (There is no causality between the two factors, despite haccks's claim.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit and @ haccks thanks to both of you for your comments.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit; After addition of second reference, as per suggested by you, now this answer is outdated.

Answer (score -1):

printf evaluates nothing. It is the compiler that evaluates arguments of a function (that is it is the compiler that generates the object code) and the order in which the arguments will be evaluated in C is unspecified. So the compiler may evaluates them in any order.

Comment: That is about the order of evaluation. But you forgot about the side-effects "modifying i multiple times without an intervening sequence point"

Comment: @wildplasser I have forgot nothing because the side effects are secondary relative to the order of evaluation of arguments.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: What total nonsense. Sequencing issues render everything else irrelevant.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Total nonsense is what you have written because if the order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified then there is no sense to speak about sequantial points.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow; I agreed with you.

Comment: @wildplasser; C11 changes that rule. Now its all about *sequencing*.

Comment: No, the order of side-effects is completely unrelated to the order of evaluation. Only sequence points matter wrt side effects.

Comment: @wildplasser; **C11: 6.5 Expressions:**

*If a side effect on a scalar object is **unsequenced** relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings*

Comment: @wildplasser  It is evident that you are saying a nonsense. What will the sequence point be if the order is unspecified?!

Comment: The only relevant sequence point is the calling of the function. Once the code "inside" the function is executed, all side effects should have taken place. (in this case: two "conflicting" side effects)

Comment: @wildplasser; Did you read the quote from standard in my last comment?

Comment: Yes. In this case there is no difference, because i's value is being modified twice (and there is no order implied by the order of evaluation)