# int a = 1; printf("%d, %d\n", (a++), a);

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    int a = 1;
    printf("%d, %d\n", a++, a);
    a = 1;
    printf("%d, %d\n", (a++), a);
    a = 1;
    printf("%d, %d\n", ++a, a);
}
```

I wonder Why is this result

```
1, 2
1, 2
2, 2
```

rather than

```
1, 2
2, 2
2, 2
```

By the way, I use visual studio 2013 to build this.

Comment: [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: Undefined and unspecified behavior.

Comment: See [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/949433/1708801) but there is a better duplicate someplace

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour A closer dupe : [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27877872/2173917).

Comment: @SouravGhosh But don't use closed questions as duplicates: use one of the threads listed below "frequent", because every "close as duplicate" counts towards the question becoming on of the "frequent" ones.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points Could also be the duplicate

Comment: @SouravGhosh it is heavily downvoted which makes it a bad dup for me but the [duplicate is is linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/q/376278/1708801) is good.

Comment: @Lundin crossing tags is not good and there are definitely better C duplciates

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour In this case, there's really not any notable differences between the C and C++ languages.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Right. Understood.

Comment: @Lundin I did not vote for dupe. Was just suggesting an alternate read. :-)

Comment: I get `1,1  1,1  2,2` which makes no sense whether you look at left-to-right evaluation or right-to-left. Undefined behaviour.