# How I get this output while passing incremented address of an array to a function?

Tags: c, pointers

```
 print(int*a,int*b,int*c,int*d,int*e){
   printf("\n%d %d %d %d %d %d",*a,*b,*c,*d,*e);
 }

 main(){
  static int arr[]={97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104};
  int *ptr=arr+1;
  print(++ptr,ptr--,ptr,ptr++,++ptr);
  return 1;
  }
```

O/P: `100 100 100 99 100 (some -ve values)` on GCC & turbo C

According to my understanding, the `ptr` points to `98` first, then `++ptr` is passed which makes it to point `99`.How in the world it prints `100`? Even then, it does not decrements the `ptr` till 3rd argument and prints it again.What's going on?

Comment: This invokes undefined behaviour, so it can be whatever

Comment: Function arguments [aren't evaluated in a specified order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376278/parameter-evaluation-order-before-a-function-calling-in-c), left-to-right or otherwise. This is one of many possible outputs from such a program - it's undefined behavior, and would likely be different on different compilers. No reason to ask *why*, since you can't rely on it. The "random" last number is due to the extra `%d` in your `printf()`, with no matching parameter.

Comment: Just for fun, the answer using clang is `99 99 98 98 100` and the answer using gcc is `100 100 100 99 100`. So it just goes to show that compilers do take advantage of undefined behavior in different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whow ! Your print function has 6 %d, and you only pass 5 int values => undefined behaviour

You are modifying more than once ptr in a single call (*) => undefined behaviour

I would say that the compiler can do anything without you can say it is wrong ...

(*) the order of the operations in a single instruction is undefined (except some explicit cases) : 6.5 §2-3 : *Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value
modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.* and *Except as specified
later (for the function-call (), &&, ||, ?:, and comma operators), the order of evaluation
of subexpressions and the order in which side effects take place are both unspecified.*

Answer (score 1):

The above code will result multiple warnings which may lead to undefined behaviour in multiple systems

```
print(++ptr,ptr--,ptr,ptr++,++ptr);
```

> multiple unsequenced modifications to 'ptr'
>         [-Wunsequenced]

```
because in my compiler it is giving output as below :
99 99 98 98 100 0
```