# Is writing 3 instructions separated by comma `,` undefined behaviour?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, comma-operator

I think that I saw somewhere that writing more than 1 instruction separated by a comma `,` is undefined behavior.

So does the following code generate undefined behavior?

```
for (i=0, j=3, k=1; i<3 && j<9 && k<5; i++, j++, k++) {
    printf("%d %d %d\n", i, j, k);
}
```

because there are 3 instructions separated by a comma `,` :

```
i++, j++, k++
```

Comment: Nope, that isn't undefined. Why do you think it should be? It's only using and updating one variable in each sequence-point.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I think that `i++, i+=5` in the same  sequence point is not valid

Comment: Yes it is. The comma operator introduces a sequence point so it is valid.

Comment: @MOHAMED: You will have problem with`foo(i++, i+=5)`. Here, the coma is not the operator but a argument separator.

Comment: ..but because arguments are pushed right-to-left (cdecl), first 5 will be added to i and the result pushed, then i is pushed and then i is incremented. I believe this is then well defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *writing more than 1 instruction separated by comma , is undefined behaviour.*

Nope, it's not the general case.

In your case, `i++, j++, k++` is perfectly valid.

FWIW, as per `C11`, chapter §6.5.17, [*Comma operator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) (emphasis mine)

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; **there is a
>   sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand.** Then the right
>   operand is evaluated; [...]

---

[Note]: You might have got confused by seeing something along the line of

```
  printf("%d %d %d", i++, ++i, i);
```

kind of statement, but do note, there the `,` is not a comma operator altogether  (rather, a separator for supplied arguments) and the sequencing does not happen. So, those kind of statements *are* UB.

Again, referring to the standard, footnote 3 for the same chapter

> <sup>As indicated by the syntax, the **comma operator** (as described in this subclause) **cannot appear in contexts where a comma is used to separate items in a list** (such as arguments to functions or lists of initializers).</sup>

Comment: I think that `i++, i+=5` in the same  sequence point is not valid

Comment: @MOHAMED nope, it's valid. see the emphasis on the quote.

Comment: does the both expression are valid in the C99?

Comment: @MOHAMED Yep, absolutely.

Comment: In the `printf` using cdecl, wouldn't first i be pushed, then i incremented and pushed and then i pushed and incremented? Taking i=5 as an example, it would be `push i=5, inc i -->6, push i=6, push 6, inc i-->7`?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie No, you're mistaken sir.  When the comma is used as separator, there is no sequence point, and having more than one _un-sequenced_ side effect is declared UB by the standard. See my updated answer. :-)

Comment: @Sourav-Gosh, your quote does not say that the comma used to separate arguments is not a sequence point. Your quote only says that if the comma is, by the syntax, used as a separator, the comma operator cannot be used.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yes, that means the properties of comma operator is also not applicable there, right?

Comment: @Sorav-Gosh, the standard says Indeed: "_The order of evaluation of the function designator, the actual arguments, and subexpressions within the actual arguments is unspecified_". See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376278/parameter-evaluation-order-before-a-function-calling-in-c, which shows I am hopelessly wrong...

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Let me say I was too lazy to do a search for the answers I knew existed. :-)  Being wrong is not bad, staying wrong is. Hope it clarified your doubts. and, (just kidding), my name is So***u***rav G***h***osh...

Answer (score 2):

Your example is perfectly fine C code.

There are instances where the comma has a different meaning, for example in declaration statements. In declaration statements, comma is used to separate the declaration of several variables.

```
int a;
a = 1,2,3;  // Ok. a is assigned the value 3.

int a = 1,2,3;   // Not ok! 
int a = 1, b = 2; // Ok! a is assigned the value 1.
```

Comment: Not every comma is a "comma operator"... the commas in `a = 1,2,3;` are, but the others you show aren't (and neither are the ones in array initializers, or the ones separating function arguments).

Comment: @Dmitri Point taken. The word operator stricken when referring to declarations. Also removed false claim that comma is used only in one other instance.