# nothing is stored as the result of fscanf

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, subscription

```
#define TERMMAX 100
typedef struct{
    int coef;
    int expon;
} poly;
poly term[TERMMAX];
int avail = 0;

#define TERMMAX 100
enter code here
int main()
{
    int i;
    FILE *fp = fopen("a.txt", "r");

    while(fscanf(fp, "%d\t%d", &term[avail].coef, &term[avail].expon) != EOF)
        avail++;
```

the fscanf part above works just fine but the following fscanf doesn't.

```
    while(fscanf(fp, "%d\t%d", &term[avail].coef, &term[avail++].expon) != EOF)
        ;
```

Nothing is stored in term[].expon. Why?

Comment: The `scanf` family does not return `EOF`, they return the number of items successfully scanned.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour due to incorrect assumptions you have made about sequence points.  Will mark as a duplicate with relevant answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameter evaluation order before a function calling in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376278/parameter-evaluation-order-before-a-function-calling-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, the order of evaluation of function parameters is unspecified by the Standard. Any side effects of function parameters are indeterminately sequenced.

Comment: _unspecified_, not _undefined_ But the OP's code invokes UB.