# increment operation in a printf statement - c programming

Tags: c, increment

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{   int i;
    i=0;
    printf("%d,%d,%d",i++,++i,i++);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 
2,3,0
I expect the output to be:2,2,0
Can someone explain how it actually gets evaluated

Comment: Please elaborate your expectation. Why are you expecting "2,3,0"? I admit I expected "0,2,2". "0" because it is a postincrement, not done before reading the value. First "2" because the previous postincrement and a preincrement is effective when reading. Second "2" because, again, the postincrement did not get effective before reading.

Comment: Why are you expecting "3,2,0"? Obviously is what I meant to ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376278/parameter-evaluation-order-before-a-function-calling-in-c)

Comment: sorry, expected is 2,2,0. But what i get after compilation is 2,3,0.. and i don't know how is that

Comment: The question has been classified as "duplicate", i.e. the question and answer is already on Stackoverflow. The official other question discusses undefined behaviour. My recommendation is on why/that evaluation of parameters to functions is unpredictable (from compiler to compiler); quite interesting. Basically compilers can do anyting they like for optimisation. You must not attempt anything which requires prediction of parameter evaluation order.