# pointer and array practice issue

Tags: c

I am learning C programming by myself, and stuck with this practice

```
int a[] = {5,7,9,11,13};
int *p;
int i = 2;
p = a;
*(p++) = ++i;
printf("%d %d %d %d", a[0], a[i++], *p, *(p+2));
// output: 3 11 7 11
```

My understanding is that

1.define an array `a` and initialise it with values 5,7,9,11,13

2.define pointer p

3.define `i` and initialise it with value 2

4.p points to array a

5.p[1] = 3;

6. a[0] = 5, a[3] = 11, *p = p[0] = 5, *(p+2) = p[2] = 9

//output: 5 11 5 9

But they are totally wrong !

I may need detailed explanation for this.

Please help me and many thanks!

Comment: `p++` is not the same as `++p`.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly based on this question?

Comment: OT: [In C "declaring" and "defining" not necessarily is the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration). All your examples in fact "define" and not just *only* "declare". I adjusted your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is correct till 3.

4 - `p` points to the first element of `a`.

5 - You are using the post increment operator. So `p`'s old value will be used and `p` will be incremented (meaning `p` will now point to the second element in `a`). So this is equivalent to `p[0] = i + 1; p = p + 1; i = i + 1;`
At this point `p` is pointing to the second element of `a` and the first element of `a` is changed to `3`. `i` is also `3` at this point.

6. `a[0] = 3`, `a[i++] = a[3] = 11`, `*p = a[1] = 7`, `*(p+2) = a[3] = 11`.

This is exactly the output you get - See [here](https://ideone.com/pdi00T).

Comment: So " *(p++) = ++i; " means that p[0] = 3 ( a[0] = 3 ) and then p move forward to  a[1]. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

For the line `*(p++) = ++i;`
This sets the value of `a[0]` to 3. Note since ++ is after `p`, it evaluates p = p + 1 after the expression.

`a[i++]` is `a[3]` which is 11. Note we start from 0 when counting.

We incremented `p` in the line `*(p++) = ++i;` therefore `p` points to `a[1]` which is 3.

Lastly `*(p+2)` means that `p` now points to `a[3]` which is 11.

There you have it `3 11 7 11`

Comment: `*(p+2)` doesn't modify `p`, your wording seems to indicate otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
int a[] = {5,7,9,11,13};
p = a;
```

looks like below

```
 ---------------------------------
 |  5  |  7  |  9  |  11  |  13  |
 ---------------------------------
 0x100  0x104  0x108 ..(lets assume bas address of a is 0x100)
 a
 p <-- p pints to base address of a
```

Next when you do like

```
*(p++) = ++i; /* ++i means 3 */
```

`p++` results in same(post increment rule) address in this expression so `3` got assigned to `0x100` memory location, in the next iteration `p` points to `0x104` memory location, so now array `a` looks like below

```
 -----------------------------------------
 |  3(5<--old)  |  7  |  9  |  11  |  13  |
 -----------------------------------------
 0x100          0x104  0x108 ..
 a               |
                 p <-- p points here
```

Next when the below `printf()` executes as below

```
printf("%d %d %d %d", a[0], a[i++], *p, *(p+2));
```

lets solve one by one

```
*(p+2) == *(0x104 + 2*4)
        == 11 (prints 11)
```

And then 
`*p` yields in `7` as `p` points to `0x104` memory location.

and

`a[i++]` yields in `a[3]` i.e `11` but for next expression `i` becomes `4`.

and

`a[0]` prints `3` as I pointed in above figure. hence it prints

```
3 11 7 11.
```

Side note, function parameters are not evaluated in a defined order in `C`, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376278/parameter-evaluation-order-before-a-function-calling-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
*(p++) = ++i;
```

uses a mix of pre- and post-increments. When you have trouble understanding such code, you should rewrite the code so that only a single thing happens in each line.

In this case it can be rewritten to:

```
i = i + 1;   // From ++i which is the pre-increment, i.e. increment first and
             // then use the new value

*p = i;      // The assignment without pre/post increments

p = p + 1;   // From p++ which is the post-increment, i.e. use the current value and
             // then increment afterwards
```

Now you have 3 simple statements that makes it easier to understand the code.

Comment: I would immediately fire anyone who wrote that line of code in a real program.