# About printf function and postfix increment operator (i++) in while loop. I want to know about procedure of the printf function

Tags: c, while-loop, printf, increment, operator-keyword

I want to understand about the procedure of 'printf' function with postfix increment operator.
I debuged these codes and found something that each 'printf' function actives after the end of the while loop.

I expected the result is like these at the second while loop
0 x 0 = 0
1 x 1 = 1
2 x 2 = 4
3 x 3 = 9
but it was wrong

I want to know about flow of the arguments and why the result printed out like this. ;(
Sorry for my poor English and I hope you guys help me solve this problem. thank you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;

    //test while and postfix increment operator

    //first while
    while (num1 < 30)
    {
        printf("%d x %d = %d\n", num1++, num2++, num1 * num2);
        //the results
        //0 x 0 = 1
        //1 x 1 = 4
        //2 x 2 = 9
        //3 x 3 = 16 ...
        //the procedure of the printf function is from left to right?
        //the flow of arguments is from left to right
    }


    //reset
    num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
    printf("\n");


    //second while
    while(num1 < 30)
    {
        printf("%d x %d = %d\n", num1, num2, (num1++) * (num2++));
        //the results
        //1 x 1 = 0
        //2 x 2 = 1
        //3 x 3 = 4
        //4 x 4 = 9...
        //the procedure of the printf function is from right to left?
        //the flow of arguments is from right to left
        //...why..?
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In what scenario would one *need* to do this?  Wouldn't it be clearer just to avoid using expressions w/ side effects as parameters to a function call?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parameter evaluation order before a function calling in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376278/parameter-evaluation-order-before-a-function-calling-in-c)

Comment: This is an undefined behaviour. order of evaluation is not defined in C

Comment: [Exhibit A](https://godbolt.org/z/n75TG9) and [Exhibit B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings)

Comment: note: undefined ≠ unspecified

Comment: Please stop writing 'clever', (difficult to understand, test and debug), code:(

Answer (score 0):

There are several duplicates of this question; you're running into the less-obvious form of the problem.

The issue is this:

> **6.5 Expressions**
> ...
> 2    If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect
> on the same scalar object or *a value computation using the value of the same scalar
> object*, the behavior is undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the
> subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side
> effect occurs in any of the orderings.<sup>84)</sup>

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

In the `printf` call, the expressions `num1++` and `num2++` have side effects - they change the values stored in those variables.  However, you're also attempting to use those variables in a value computation (`num1 * num2`) without an intervening *sequence point* - a point in the program's execution where the side effects of `++` have been applied to both `num1` and `num2`.  C does not require that function arguments be evaluated left to right, nor does it require that the side effect of the `++` operator be applied immediately after evaluation.

The behavior is explicitly called out as being *undefined* - neither the compiler nor runtime environment are required to handle the situation in any particular way.

To accomplish what you want, you need to separate out the updates to `num1` and `num2`:

```
while ( num1 < 30 )
{
  printf( "%d x %d = %d\n", num1, num2, num1 * num2 );
  num1++;
  num2++;
}
```

Alternately, you can rewrite this as a `for` loop as follows:

```
for ( num1 = 0, num2 = 0; num1 < 30; num1++, num2++ )
  printf( "%d x %d = %d\n", num1, num2, num1 * num2 );
```