# Explanation of output of program

Tags: c, sizeof, operator-precedence

Can anyone explain why this program prints 4 1 instead of 4 2?

Shouldn't pre increment operator which has higher precedence get executed first and print 4 2?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   int a=1;
   printf ("%ld %d",sizeof(++a),a);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The order in which the arguments are evaluated is not specified, and this is UB

Comment: Even `sizeof(++a)` by itself is quite peculiar. https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP44-C.+Do+not+rely+on+side+effects+in+operands+to+sizeof%2C+_Alignof%2C+or+_Generic

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376278/parameter-evaluation-order-before-a-function-calling-in-c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior/34536741#34536741

Comment: Both links explain quite well the issue.

Comment: @WilliamPursell are you sure about the dupes? With `sizeof(a++)`, `a++` is never evaluated,  therefore his code is equivalent to `printf ("%ld %d",sizeof(a),a);` which is perfectly legal, no UB involved here.

Comment: Although the presence of `sizeof` does make this slightly different, the question "Shouldn't pre increment operator...get executed first" shows that the OP needs to read those questions.

Comment: The definite answer is Steve Summit's, I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 6):

Although you've already gotten several answers, I want to provide one more, because your question actually contained three separate misunderstandings, and I want to touch on all of them.

First of all, `sizeof` is a special operator which, by definition, does *not* evaluate its argument (that is, whatever subexpression it's taking the size of).  So `sizeof(++a)` does *not* increment `a`.  And `sizeof(x = 5)` would *not* assign 5 to `x`.  And `sizeof(printf("Hello!"))` would *not* print "Hello".

Second, if we got rid of the `sizeof`, and simply wrote

```
printf("%d %d", ++a, a);
```

we would *not* be able to use precedence to figure out the behavior.  Precedence is an important concept, but in general it does *not* help you figure out the behavior of confusing operations involving `++`.

Finally, the perhaps surprising answer is that if you write

```
printf("%d %d", ++a, a);
```

it is *not possible* to figure out what it will do at all.  It's basically undefined.  (Specifically: in any function call like `printf("%d %d", x, y)` it's *unspecified* which order the arguments get evaluated in, so you don't know whether `x` or `y` gets evaluated first -- although there is an order.  But then, when one of them is `a` and one of them is `++a`, you have a situation where `a` is both being modified and having its value used, so there's no way to know whether the old or the new value gets used, and this makes the expression *undefined*.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior/34536741#34536741) for more on this issue.)

P.S. One more issue I forgot to mention, as noted by @Vlad from Moscow: `%ld` is not a reliable way to print the result of `sizeof`, which is a value of type `size_t`.  You should use `%zu` if you can, or `%u` after casting to `(unsigned)` if you can't.

Comment: "it is not possible to figure out what it will do." Because it can increment during before or after?

Comment: This will benefit from a standard citation(s)

Comment: @dreamcrash It is not possible because it's inherently confusing, and because there's no rule which defines the answer.  The comma separating function arguments is not a comma operator and does not introduce a sequence point.  So if you call `f(a, a++)`, there's no rule to say whether the first argument passed is the old or the incremented value of `a`.  Furthermore, this is one of the situations that makes the whole expression (and, therefore, the whole program) undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation that is why one rather do f(a, a); a++.

Answer (score 3):

From the C Standard *6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 2 The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
> may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is
> determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If
> the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand
> is evaluated; **otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result
> is an integer constant**.

So the task of the `sizeof` operator is to determine the type of the expression used as an operand and then knowing the type of its operand to return the size of an object of the type. If the operand is not a variable length array then the expression used as an operand is not evaluated and the value returned by the `sizeof` operator is calculated at compile-time.

Thus this call

```
printf ("%ld %d",sizeof(++a),a);
```

is equivalent to the call

```
printf ("%ld %d",sizeof( int ),a);
```

and in your system `sizeof( int )` is equal to `4`.

So it does not matter what expression is used (except using a variable length array the size of which is calculated at run time) as an operand. It is the type of the expression that is important. For example you could even write

```
printf ( "%zu %d\n", sizeof( ( ++a, ++a, ++a, ++a, ++a ) ), a );
```

and got the same result.

Pay attention to that you should use the conversion specifier `zu` used for values of the type `size_t` instead of `ld` used for signed values. That is you need to write

```
printf ("%zu %d",sizeof(++a),a);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [c99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf),

> the sizeof() operator only takes into account the type of the operand, which may be an expression or the name of a type (i.e int, double, float etc) and not the value obtained on evaluating the expression.

Hence, the operand inside the sizeof() operator is not evaluate.

Comment: C17 makes it explicit: "If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated;
**otherwise, the operand is not evaluated** and the result is an integer constant."  6.5.3.4 (2).

Comment: @NateEldredge Good find. So C17 is the earliest one with this provision?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I didn't check the ones in between.

Comment: The operand of `sizeof` is never evaluated, otherwise constructs like `char *p = NULL; p = malloc(length * sikzeof(*p));` wouldn't work.

Comment: @NateEldredge C11 does not have it indeed. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4p2 UPD: Ah sorry, it is in fact there

Comment: Actually even C89 had it: 3.3.3.4 "The size is determined from the type of the operand, **which is not itself evaluated.**"  And C99 has the same language as C17.