# C99 parameter evaluation before C function is called

Tags: function, parameters, call, c99, evaluation

I know that this question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376278/parameter-evaluation-order-before-a-function-calling-in-c), but I feel like I don't fully understand C99 standard. I want to ask about parameter evaluation itself, for example:

```
int index = 0;
sprintf(somebuf, "some-text-%d", index++);
```

So, it seems like index is not incremented before function call (I got some-text-0 as a result). Is it expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the post-increment operator (`++` follows `index`), the value is used first, then incremented. If you wanted to use the incremented value, you should have used the pre-increment operator (`++index`). FYI, this dates back to the earliest versions of C.