# A 7 Line Simple C Code That I Can't Figure Out

Tags: c, pointers, operators, logical-operators

Can someone please explain why the output here is 2 1 1, what does c prioritise here? how come the output of i++ is 1. Thanks in advance
~

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
int i=1;
int *p=&i;
printf("%d%d%d\n",*p,i++,i);
}
```

Comment: FYI, `main` always returns `int`.  Always.

Comment: Recommendation: When you have a C question don't tag C++. Both languages evolved from the same root, but they look less and less alike every day.

Comment: My understanding is that this is undefined behavior.  The compiler is allowed to evaluate the parameters in any order before passing them to the function.

Comment: To build on what Thomas mentioned, `void main()` has never been a valid signature for `main` in either C or C++, though some compilers do allow it as a nonstandard extension. See [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/11082165)

Comment: There is no prioritization of the order of parameter evaluation. This allows the compiler to generate faster code by reordering to maximize any advantages. [See this documentation page for more information on similar gotchas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order) See the link at the very bottom of that page to see how the rules differ in C++

Comment: @ThomasMatthews FWIW I think the correct term is unspecified behavior in this case, not undefined behavior.

Comment: On a test you would have to answer "Unspecified". If that's not an option your instructor probably shouldn't be teaching C.

Comment: "what does c prioritise here? " Nothing here.  `printf("%d%d%d\n",*p,i++,i);` is bad code.  Don't code this way.

Comment: this is a question in a computer science test

Comment: ProgEnthusiast,  `printf("%d%d%d\n",*p,i++,i)` may even cause a bus fault as `i++,i` may happen at the same time.  Its UB.

Comment: Closely related-if not an outright duplicate: [Parameter evaluation order before a function calling in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376278/parameter-evaluation-order-before-a-function-calling-in-c) Second answer is most relevant here.

Comment: @ProgEnthusiast Since you mentioned that this came up on a test, it may be worth bringing this issue to your instructor's attention. As backing, you can bring up the relevant part of the C99 standard, which would be §6.5.2.2/10. You can get a copy of the standard here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf. See page 72 for the relevant paragraph, which reads _"The order of evaluation of the function designator, the actual arguments, and subexpressions within the actual arguments is unspecified, but there is a  sequence point before the actual call"_.

Comment: I've seen this on written tests in the past as a sort-of booby trap question. I know the instructor knew it was unspecified because he covered it in class. If he hadn't, I'd have called him on it. I'd try to be less of a dick about it these days, mind you. Somewhere along the line I learned it's rude to blurt out "WRONG!" during presentations.

Comment: @Brian: The C standard does not make `void main()` an invalid signature. It makes `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` valid in hosted environments and leaves it open whether there are other valid signatures, so a C implementation may define others. In a freestanding environment, the standard does not define what the type of `main` is at all or even whether it is the function called at startup, so an implementation must define it.

Comment: This is a multiple choice test, the choices were: 1) the code won't compile 2) it will display 1 2 1 3) it will display 2 2 1 4) it will display something else. So there isn't actually an answer that says "unspecified". The thing there's 7 other questions that are just like this one.

Comment: @ProgEnthusiast: The test is defective. This is a well-known situation in which the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: Although this example has just one increment operator, it nevertheless is essentially the same as the duplicate.  Incrementing `i` and referencing it directly in the argument list is undefined behaviour in its own right; also, referencing it via `*p` just adds another part to the undefined behaviour.  Another referenced question is itself deemed a duplicate of the question to which this question is closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Brian The correct term in this case is *undefined*.  There are no sequence points between the evaluation of the several arguments in a function call.

Comment: @user4581301 On a test you would want to answer Undefined, if at all possible.

Comment: @ProgEnthusiast I won't blame you a bit if you don't feel like trying, but there are multiple people here who would back you up if you wanted to lodge a formal complaint with your school's administration about the incompetence of the person setting this test.

Comment: Even though the question may be flawed, actually enough information is available to determine what happened in this particular case. If the output was `2 1 1`, then clearly the first argument `*p` was processed *last*, because the value was already incremented. That means we can also determine that `i` was processed *first*, otherwise the output would be `2 1 2`. Therefore the arguments were processed right to left. But there is no way to guarantee this always happens. The compiler could have chosen differently. All possible outputs are `1 1 1`, `2 1 1`, `1 1 2`, `2 1 2` and faulty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior of this code is not defined by the C standard per C 2018 6.5 2:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined…

`i++` has the side effect of updating `i` with its incremented value. The function call arguments also include `*p` and `i`, both of which refer to `i` and use its value. `i` is a scalar object. The order of evaluation of function call arguments and their side effects are unsequenced (meaning the C standard does not impose any ordering requirements on them). Therefore, all the conditions for the rule above are met, so the behavior is not defined by the C standard.