# C printf() function order of evaluations?

Tags: c, function, output, printf

What is the output?
Please kindly give answer with valid explanation.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d %d", printf("Hello World"), printf("New World"));
}
```

It's giving:

```
New WorldHello World11 9
```

I don't know why it printed first the "New World" rather than "Hello World". Please explain the output.

Comment: Tell us what *you* think, and why?

Comment: It's giving New World Hello World 11 9. I don't know why it printed first the New World rather than Hello World. Whereas the actual order of arguments is not followed while printing.

Comment: [Parameter evaluation order before a function calling in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376278/parameter-evaluation-order-before-a-function-calling-in-c)

Comment: The parameter values in a function call may be computed in any order.

Comment: ...and length results will still be output inthe same order, so they don't necessarily match the visible output.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: It is entirely proper to teach the fact that the C standard does not sequence argument evaluation and to demonstrate that with an example that counters an expectation that order is left-to-right.

Comment: Function arguments can be evaluated *in any order*; in your case `printf("New World")` is evaluated (called) before `printf("Hello World")`.  The *result* of `printf("Hello World")` is printed first, even though it wasn't evaluated first.

Answer (score 0):

You should first remember that there is very little magic in C language: it was initially designed to blindly obey its programmer and still now mostly does what it is asked.

Here what happens: you call the `printf` function with 3 arguments: a string (`"%d %d"`), and 2 expressions that happen to be function calls.

So the compiler first evaluates the function arguments (in an unspecified order). Each `printf` function calls does its own output and returns (as any `printf` call does) the number of characters. The reason why you first see `Hello world` and `New world` in the order dictated by your specific C implementation.

Then the outer printf is called with parameters `"%d %d"`, `9` and `11` (the return values of the inner printf calls...) and normally displays `9 11`.

No magic...

Comment: I still didn't get the reason why the order of output is changed at the time of printing. Can you please explain more why the given order of arguments is not executed as it should be?

Comment: There is no "it should be". The arguments are evaluated in **unspecified** order. Also see the link by @Joel.

Comment: @ThangTons: There is no order that the arguments “should be” evaluated in. The C standard does not specify they must be evaluated in any particular order. Nothing says they are evaluated left to right. Arguments do not even have to be evaluated in an order at all; a compiler may evaluate part of one argument, then part of another, then part of the first, and so on (aside from sequencing constraints in the arguments themselves). E.g., `printf("%d %d", f()+g(), h()+i())` may be evaluated in the order `f`, `i`, `h`, `g`.